# Javascript search function causes page to jump down on product load

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple javascript search function in my website that works great, however, upon striking enter, it loads the product page somewhat some amount down the page. I can't get to the bottom of it.
Here is some example code of the javascript search function I've built. The page in question if you wish to test is https://black-rhodium.co.uk/Products

I have taken out the chatbot function in the bottom right to test, and that made no difference.

No errors in console/sources (opera).

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport"
content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum- 
scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<title>Tuto</title>
</head>


<body style=" background-color: rgb(4, 41, 255);">

<input type="search" autocomplete="off" value="" placeholder="Search here..." id="search" 
onchange="openPage()">

<script>
function openPage() {
var x = document.getElementById("search").value;

if (x.toLowerCase() === "Wave".toLowerCase()) {
window.top.location = ("/Products#!/products/wave-usb---dealer-only---click-for-more-info");
}
    
if (x.toLowerCase() === "Wave USB".toLowerCase()) {
window.top.location = ("/Products#!/products/wave-usb---dealer-only---click-for-more-info");
}
    
if (x.toLowerCase() === "Waltz links".toLowerCase()) {
window.top.location = ("/Products#!/products/waltz-speaker-links");
}
    
if (x.toLowerCase() === "Waltz speakerlinks".toLowerCase()) {
window.top.location = ("/Products#!/products/waltz-speaker-links");
}
    
}            
    
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: You can set the hash using `location.hash`. Also default browser navigation does not work. As to your problem it's probably caused by redrawing the main content part, when it's absent the page gets scrolled down to whatever, I'm not sure.

Comment: what is your goal? what expected result do you want to see?